# $state.go using in transition hooks (transition.Onstart)with latest UI router framework (1.0.16)

Tags: angularjs

When am using  `$state.go` in transition hooks for ex. `$transition.onStart` it's giving me transition rejected it's superseded

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and must read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the same.

Comment: Does the `$state.go` execute or it does not occur at all? In the latest framework, errors (like `transition superseded`) no longer silently fail https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#default-error-handler ... do you have a code snippet of the full onStart callback you're using?

Comment: yes its executing( to particular route which mentioned in the ex: ````$state.go('app.noAccess');````)  but its again comes to ````$transition.onStart```` hook and throwing error on the console.(but this error is not impacting on the application) So here onStart hook calling one more time. is there any way to stop executing onStart hook again.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return a promise inside of `$transition.onStart` -- in the case you want to cancel the $transition that just started, the promise should reject or you can just return false (per [hook documentation](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/transition.html#hookresult)).

For your specific angularjs case, you can do something like `return $q.reject();` if $q has been injected already or try `return false;`

Comment: ok. but i want to redirect to some other page like 'access Denied' page when promise is rejected. how can i do this.

Comment: in that case, you can catch the promise and do a $state.go... but that may keep the transition superseeded error (which is expected and harmless)

Comment: actually am calling API if it returns expected value (ex. true) am allowing to go to the desired page, if its not, am restricting to ''access Denied' page. its working as expected. anyway thank you @kathrine R